# Get list of classes in project libraries (C#)

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I get in C# a list of all the classes from all the libraries I use in the project.
For example, if my project uses `System, System.Collections` I expect to have in the list

```
System.Console
System.Version
...
```

Comment: It's easy to list all classes _available_ in an assembly, but why do you need the ones _used_? You'd need to parse through your code line by line to figure out which classes are used, that's not something reflection can do by itself.

Comment: To find used classes you'd need a Roslyn Analyzer. Finding unused classes is already available in Resharper, if not Visual Studio itself. Open-source analyzers like Roslynator probably check for this as well

Comment: If I have a name of a class is there any way to check to which library he belongs?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem here, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to have a list of all the classes the libraries I use in the project contains. Even if I don't actually use them in the project itself.
If I can check if a class belongs to a specific library even tho it's not efficient I can make a loop for all the classes in the assembly and check for each one if he belongs to a library I use in my project, if there is an easier way to do so it's even better.

Comment: Yes, but **why** do you need this? There's nothing you can really do with that information.